# How do I add only the positive numbers in a ruby array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, math, conditional-statements

I'm new to ruby and I'm trying to make a method that gets the sum of all the positive numbers any array of numbers. Here is an example:

```
arr=(1,3,-1,7,4,-9,0,3)
```

This is what I tried so far, but it just gets the sum including negative values.

```
def positive_sum(arr)

   arr.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x  }

end
```

I want to answer to be: 1+3+7+4+3 = 18, so it ignores all the negative numbers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `arr.sum(0) { |n| [n,0].max }` or `arr.select { |n| n > 0 }.sum(0)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: `arr.select(&:positive?).sum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
> arr=[1,3,-1,7,4,-9,0,3]
=> [1, 3, -1, 7, 4, -9, 0, 3]
irb(main):005:0> arr.select{|e| e>=0}
=> [1, 3, 7, 4, 0, 3]
```

to get the positives and then use the `sum` method:

```
> arr.select{|e| e>=0}.sum
=> 18
```

There is also the shortcut of `.select(&:positive?)`:

```
> arr.select(&:positive?)
=> [1, 3, 7, 4, 3]
```

And then you can use `.sum` on that.

If you want to use a conditional with `.inject` you need to understand that each condition needs to return a value that is used in the reduction being done by `inject`. Otherwise, you will mix a `nil` from the failed condition and `.inject` won't know how to add that to a sum. The solution is to use a ternary that returns the sum so far instead of sum+n only.

Here is an example of a conditional `.inject` using the `test ? true : false` [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) to return the proper values when the condition is true and when false:

```
> arr.inject{|s,n| n>0 ? s+n : s }
=> 18
```

Or just filter out the negatives first then use inject as the summation method:

```
> arr.select(&:positive?).inject(:+)
=> 18
```

Same methods work with `.reduce` as well:

```
> arr.reduce{ |s,n| n>0 ? s+=n : s }
=> 18
> arr.select(&:positive?).reduce(:+)
=> 18
```

You can also use `.partition` to separate the positives from the negatives and deal with both:

```
> arr.partition{|e| e>0}.each{|sa| p sa, sa.sum }
[1, 3, 7, 4, 3]
18
[-1, -9, 0]
-10
```

Or:

```
> arr.partition{|e| e>0}.map{|sa| sa.sum}
=> [18, -10]
```

Ruby is a very flexible language...

Comment: Thanks, this worked, another thing I found worked was
  **arr.select{ |x| x > 0 }.reduce(:+).to_i**
    or
  **arr.select{ |x| x > 0 }.reduce(0, :+)**

Answer (score 0):

For the solution from @dawg,the inject method solution should put the initial elements so that it can start from 0, otherwise, it will start the arr[0], if arr[0] is a negative num, then the sum is not right

```
arr.inject(0) { |s, n| n>=0 ? s+n : s}
```